# Contacts stuck in wait activity

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, activity

I have created a journey with the entry event being a Salesforce entry event, the DE related to this entry event is updated based upon a change in Salesforce CRM - as soon as a certain field is filled that triggers the journey - this entry event works.

After that a welcome email is sent - this email is sent correctly. After that the contact enters the wait event - but the contact never passes that wait event.

I did test the journey by deleting the wait event and then the email is actually sent. So it looks like the contact does not pass the wait event.

Can anyone explain me why the contact does not pass the wait event?

Help is much appreciated, 
Regards, 
Marloes Florijn

Comment: How is your Wait event configured? Are you specifying a set time or are you using attribute based setting?

Comment: Set time - 1 minute

Comment: Then it sounds more like a MC issue. Try creating a new version of the Journey and then give it another go.

Comment: Is your account on S7 by chance? Have an ongoing case with SF support for the exact same issue - it's been escalated but no cause identified yet.

Comment: Have seen same behavior as @AnonWonderer above.  Contacts eventually existed the Wait step.

Comment: Yes, I am also on S7. Thanks for this. We will be also logging a case. What is the current feedback/work around from Salesforce?

Comment: They are seeing timeout errors for these contacts. They thought it was due to a degradation on S7 causing timeouts for wait periods, but since they claim that specific issue was resolved and it's still happening, they don't know what the cause is. R&D team is investigating - haven't been provided a workaround yet.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that, generally, the recommendation is to not have those short wait step activities. Is it just for testing or?

Comment: Yes, this is just for testing purposes. But still it should work, so we are keeping the case open with Salesforce as I am very interested in there response.